# Problems handling NaN Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Im trying to make new Files based on Data which has the same names. Right now Im working only on Lists, that store the matching Names of the Rows.
My Problem is that All NaN values aren't stored on one List. Im guessing that NaN is just always unequal to NaN because there is no value.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('/Users/jedknauer/code/Python xlsx/OPOS-Liste Kreditoren zum 31.08.2021.xlsx')
(df.sort_values("Unnamed: 2",ascending = False)["Unnamed: 2"])

#df1 = df.loc[df["Unnamed: 2"]== "Kluxen & Co. Immobilien"][]


#for index, row in df.iterrows():
#    print(index, row["Unnamed: 2"])

new_objects = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    b = row["Unnamed: 2"]
    is_new = False
    
    if (index == 0):
        new_objects.append([b,[]])
    for i  in new_objects:
        
        if (b == i[0]):
            is_new = False
            i[-1].append(b)
            break; 
        if(b != i[0] ):
            is_new = True
    if (is_new ==  True):
        new_objects.append([b,[]])
        is_new == False

print(new_objects)
```

This Is the Output of new_objects:

```
[['Beschriftung', ['Beschriftung']], ['Korg & More', ['Korg & More', 'Korg & More']],
 ['B.& K. Baumgärtel GmbH', ['B.& K. Baumgärtel GmbH', 'B.& K. Baumgärtel GmbH', 'B.& K. Baumgärtel GmbH']],
 ['hallo PC', ['hallo PC']], ['Bundesanzeiger Verlag', []], ['Steinway & Sons', ['Steinway & Sons']],
 [nan, []], [nan, []], ['Mach Ernst', ['Mach Ernst', 'Mach Ernst']], ['Aaron Padelt', []], [nan, []], ['EP Service', []],
 [nan, []], ['Kluxen & Co. Immobilien', ['Kluxen & Co. Immobilien', 'Kluxen & Co. Immobilien', 'Kluxen & Co. Immobilien',
                                         'Kluxen & Co. Immobilien', 'Kluxen & Co. Immobilien', 'Kluxen & Co. Immobilien',
                                         'Kluxen & Co. Immobilien']],
 [nan, []], [nan, []], [nan, []], ['Universaldrucker', []], ['EMD Musik s.a.', ['EMD Musik s.a.']],
 [nan, []], ['KSC', ['KSC', 'KSC', 'KSC', 'KSC']], ['Dumrath & Fassnacht', ['Dumrath & Fassnacht']],
 [nan, []], ['Telekom Deutschland GmbH', ['Telekom Deutschland GmbH', 'Telekom Deutschland GmbH']],
 [nan, []], ['KRAVAG', []], [nan, []], [nan, []], [nan, []], [nan, []], [nan, []], [nan, []], [nan, []],
 [nan, []], ['DomainFactory GmbH', []], ['Dickau, Claudia', []], ['Klavier Atelier Blankenese', []],
 [nan, []], ['Vattenfall Europe Sales GmbH', ['Vattenfall Europe Sales GmbH']], ['Diverse Kreditoren', []], [nan, []]]
```

Comment: In the IEEE-754 standard, `NaN` indeed will always return `false` in any comparison with any other number. You can use `pd.isna()` to check if a value is `NaN`.  But your root problem here is probably the line `b = row["Unnamed: 2"]`, where pandas seems to be returning `nan` when the key isn't present. Have you considered using `row.get("Unnamed: 2", None)` to use `None` or some other default value instead of `NaN`?

Comment: Hey Just tried but the output seems to be the same.